# rails reusing view templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

A rails newbie here

I have 2 actions in my controller 1) index 2) refine_existing.
Both of them show the results in the same format.
How do I reuse the index.html.erb file?

When I try the following, it complains about refine_existing.erb not being present.

```
def refine_existing
   ...
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @results }
end
```

end

my index action looks like this

```
def index
 #some logic to get @results
 #set some session variables etc.
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @results }
 end
end
```

Do I have to refactor my index view to contain partials that
a) make the headers
b) render @results
and reuse them? 
Even though, both index.html.erb and refine_existing.html.erb will look exactly the same

Is there any way I can say in my refine_existing action to use index.erb view?

thanks in advance

Comment: The `# index.html.erb` is just a comment, for you to look at. I dislike it, since cut-n-pasting the common `respond_to do ... end` block is too likely to bring the wrong filename along with the `format.html`. If `index` and `refine_existing` will be identical, maybe you could redirect from one to the other.

Comment: The problem with redirecting to index is that it re-executes the code to get @results in index and overrides the records in refine_existing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, if you don't specify a template name Rails looks for one matching the action. You can override this by calling `render` explicitly with the desired template name. The only wrinkle is that the path is relative to TEMPLATE_ROOT, which is normally `app/views`:

```
def refine_existing
   ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :template => "<table_name>/index.html.erb" }
  end
end
```

replacing `table_name` with the "tablized" form of the model. E.g. if your controller is `PostsController`, then `posts`. So your template would then live in `app/views/posts/index.html.erb` -- if you've customized paths somehow adjust as necessary.